# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 'ip-address' closed. The same code worked on my colleagues pc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, nestjs, npm-start

I am extremely new to all of this (like less than a month new). Basically my tech lead linked us this github repo of an API that I git cloned onto my local device. I followed the instructions and used npm run start in the terminal and got this:

```
C:\Users\my_path >npm  start

> tracksol-nest-webservice@0.0.1 start
> nest start

[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] ScannerModule dependencies initialized +43ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] MssqlModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] WebAdminModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +78ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +4ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [RoutesResolver] WebAdminController {/api/web-admin}: +1ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/web-admin/:modelName, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 24508  - 28/02/2023, 12:16:18 am     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +142ms
[WEB] http://localhost:3000
```

Well so far so good? But within 30 seconds all of these scary messages popped up and the localhost:3000 is not accessible anymore.

```
(node:24508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to the-ip-address:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\my-path\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:591:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24508) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As I said in the title, my colleague manage to get it up and running smoothly while mine kept timing out. We both cloned the same github repo so the code itself is probably not the issue. My colleague and I both do not have mongoDB installed on our devices.

Things I have tried:

1. Switching my node version to the same as his -- 14.20.0
2. npm install repeatedly
3. Restarting my computer multiple times
4. recloned the same code multiple times

Comment: Did you start the mongo server?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run MongoDB server before starting the NestJS server, if you still struggle with it, please share your main.ts to review connection code block!